# Fresco crossfading within a DraweeHolder

Tags: android, facebook, image, fresco

I'm using DraweeHolder in my custom view to display image. When I want to update the image with a new resource, I create a new DraweeController, then setController to the DraweeHolder.

What I'm trying to implement is the crossfading effect between the previous and new image.
For fade in/out, I setAlpha to the drawable recursively.

```
void handleTransition(DraweeHolder draweeHolder, long startingTime) {
    Drawable drawable = draweeHolder.getTopLevelDrawable().mutate();
    int duration = 2000;
    long currTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int diff = (int) (currTime - startingTime);
    int toAlpha = Math.max(0, 255 - (255 * diff / duration));
    drawable.setAlpha(toAlpha);
    invalidate();
}


@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onDraw()");
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    synchronized (this) {
        handleTransition(draweeHolder, mCurrentTransStartTime);
    }
}
```

It seems working fine, except that onDraw will be called too many times.
However, I have no idea how can we have two images appear at the same time (crossfade) in this DraweeHolder. Even setting high/low resolution image for DraweeHolder doesn't give the option of crossfading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track. You will have to write a custom view (e.g. by extending `ImageView`). Keep in mind that you need to wire up some things in order for Drawee to work correctly, read [here](http://frescolib.org/docs/writing-custom-views.html#_) how to do that.

You will need two `DraweeHolders`. When using multiple holders it's best to keep them in a `MultiDraweeHolder`:

```
  private void init() {
    mMultiDraweeHolder = new MultiDraweeHolder<GenericDraweeHierarchy>();
    // holders for the two images to cross-fade between
    Drawable drawables[] = new Drawable[2];
    for (int i = 0; i < drawables.length; i++) {
      GenericDraweeHierarchy hierarchy = createDraweeHierarchy();
      mMultiDraweeHolder.add(DraweeHolder.create(hierarchy, getContext()));
      drawables[i] = hierarchy.getTopLevelDrawable();
    }
    mFadeDrawable = new FadeDrawable(drawables);
    // no need to override onDraw, ImageView superclass will correctly draw our fade drawable if we set it like this:
    super.setImageDrawable(mFadeDrawable);
    mCurrentIndex = 0;
  }

  void loadNextImage(DraweeController controller) {
    mCurrentIndex = (mCurrentIndex + 1) % 2;
    mMultiDraweeHolder.get(mCurrentIndex).setController(controller);
    mFadeDrawable.fadeToLayer(mCurrentIndex);
  }

  GenericDraweeHierarchy createDraweeHierarchy() {
    // create a new drawee hierarchy here,
    // as each image needs to have its own instance
  }
```

Comment: Btw, Drawee already provides FadeDrawable, so that you don't need to mess with measuring time and calculating alpha on your own.

Comment: Also, in order to wait with crossfading until the new image actually gets loaded, you can set a controller listener and do `mFadeDrawable.fadeToLayer(mCurrentIndex)` in `onFinalImageSet`.

Comment: thanks for reply. It's a good hint to use FadeDrawable. It works great now.

Comment: Can you share the full class with us?